# Python Strings and Loops to create a keyboard character pattern

Tags: python, string, loops, rotation, repeat

I am a very new learner to Python !

Strings and Loops and Loop within a loop.

I am trying to create some code that creates a very specific pattern that can be run x amount of times.

I am not sure if I should use 2 separate characters to create the pattern or if I should use a rotate/ position and print copy/commands and also I would like to ensure that the character/s stay a particular length size. I currently am using code I have created using 2 characters. (A) & (B)

I have no idea if I am using the above terms correctly -

My output is currently x amount of rows/columns of 1 character then the next character

enter the desired amount of pattern

Print Pattern name

```
A A A
A A A
A A A

B B B
B B B
B B B
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3V4B.jpg)

What I would like is row by row in a looks like step/stair

```
       A A A 
      B B B
     A A A 
   B B B 
  A A A
```

square_side = int(input("Please enter the square Step dimension  : "))

square_base = int(input("Please enter the square base dimension  : "))

print("Square AlphaBet Step Pattern")

for i in range(square_side):
for i in range(square_side):
print("A", end = '  ')
print()

for i in range(square_base):
for i in range(square_base):
print("B", end = '  ')
print()

@aymen your solution does work i would like to now what 'function' to use to then repeat that layout several times in the same rows ??

so:

```
  A A A      A A A
 B B B      B B B
A A A      A A A ?? IF that makes sense ??
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P30Y6.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you share with us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: square_side = int(input("Please enter the square Step dimension  : "))

square_base = int(input("Please enter the square base dimension  : "))

print("Square AlphaBet Step Pattern") 

for i in range(square_side):
    for i in range(square_side):
        print("A", end = '  ')
    print()

for i in range(square_base):
    for i in range(square_base):
        print("B", end = '  ')
    print()

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps you ?

```
square_side = int(input("Please enter the square Step dimension  : "))

square_base = int(input("Please enter the square base dimension  : "))

print("Square AlphaBet Step Pattern") 
max_side = square_side*2

for i in range(max_side):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        letter = " A"
    else:
        letter = " B"
    
    print(" "*(max_side-i-1) + letter*3)
```

Output:

```
      A A A
     B B B
    A A A
   B B B
  A A A
 B B B
```

Comment: yes it does, is it possible to add a function where I get the output like the above but grouped/copied several times spaced out in the same rows?

Comment: You have updated your question introducing another problem. Please post it seperatly.